# Integral of a function in a region common to two spheres.

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

While doing a problem in quantum mechanics, I came across this integral: $$\int_V d^3\vec k\frac{1}{z-\frac{k^2}{2\mu}+i0^+}.$$Where the region $V$ is the intersection of two spheres centered on $\vec p_1$ and $\vec p_2$ with common radius $\lambda$(assuming $|\vec p_1-\vec p_2|<2\lambda$). I simply cannot see how to evaluate the integral as the bounds are defined piecewise and the pieces also depend on the orientation of $(\vec p_1-\vec p_2)$. Can someone help me?

Any comments/hints will be also helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can you tell us about the parameters $z$ and $\mu$? I'm guessing $\mu$ is intended to be a positive real constant, and $z$ can be an arbitrary complex number. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, $\mu$ is a positive real quantity but for z the practice is to assume that it is real and after evaluating the integral, somehow analytically continue the result on the whole complex plane. Evaluating it for complex z doesn’t do any harm.